# Nested arrays $unwind and $group back together in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

We have three nested arrays:

1. `principalCredits` with 2 objects
2. `credits` with 2 objects each
3. `awardNominations.edges` with variable totals from 0 to 3

The task is to add a field to the third array of objects `awardNominations.edges` based on a lookup from `eventsCollection`.

Here's the data I have (simplified, can copy and paste into MongoDB Compass):

```
[{
  "principalCredits": [
    {
      "category": {
        "id": "director",
        "text": "Directors"
      },
      "totalCredits": 2,
      "credits": [
        {
          "name": {
            "id": "nm11813828",
            "nameText": {
              "text": "Pippa Ehrlich"
            },
            "awardNominations": {
              "total": 2,
              "edges": [
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "an1393007",
                    "isWinner": true,
                    "award": {
                      "id": "an1393007",
                      "year": 2020,
                      "text": "Green Warsaw Award",
                      "event": {
                        "id": "ev0003786",
                        "text": "Millennium Docs Against Gravity"
                      },
                      "category": {
                        "text": null
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "an1428940",
                    "isWinner": false,
                    "award": {
                      "id": "an1428940",
                      "year": 2021,
                      "text": "IDA Award",
                      "event": {
                        "id": "ev0000351",
                        "text": "International Documentary Association"
                      },
                      "category": {
                        "text": "Best Writing"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
              ]
            }
          },
          "category": {
            "id": "director",
            "text": "Director"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": {
            "id": "nm1624755",
            "nameText": {
              "text": "James Reed"
            },
            "awardNominations": {
              "total": 3,
              "edges": [
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "an0694012",
                    "isWinner": true,
                    "award": {
                      "id": "an0694012",
                      "year": 2015,
                      "text": "Best of Festival",
                      "event": {
                        "id": "ev0001486",
                        "text": "Jackson Wild Media Awards"
                      },
                      "category": {
                        "text": "Best of Festival"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "an0975779",
                    "isWinner": true,
                    "award": {
                      "id": "an0975779",
                      "year": 2017,
                      "text": "RTS West Television Award",
                      "event": {
                        "id": "ev0000571",
                        "text": "Royal Television Society, UK"
                      },
                      "category": {
                        "text": "Documentary"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "an0975781",
                    "isWinner": true,
                    "award": {
                      "id": "an0975781",
                      "year": 2015,
                      "text": "Grand Teton Prize",
                      "event": {
                        "id": "ev0001356",
                        "text": "Jackson Hole Film Festival"
                      },
                      "category": {
                        "text": "Best in Festival"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "category": {
            "id": "director",
            "text": "Director"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": {
        "id": "writer",
        "text": "Writers"
      },
      "totalCredits": 2,
      "credits": [
        {
          "name": {
            "id": "nm11813828",
            "nameText": {
              "text": "Pippa Ehrlich"
            },
            "awardNominations": {
              "total": 2,
              "edges": [
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "an1393007",
                    "isWinner": true,
                    "award": {
                      "id": "an1393007",
                      "year": 2020,
                      "text": "Green Warsaw Award",
                      "event": {
                        "id": "ev0003786",
                        "text": "Millennium Docs Against Gravity"
                      },
                      "category": {
                        "text": null
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "node": {
                    "id": "an1428940",
                    "isWinner": false,
                    "award": {
                      "id": "an1428940",
                      "year": 2021,
                      "text": "IDA Award",
                      "event": {
                        "id": "ev0000351",
                        "text": "International Documentary Association"
                      },
                      "category": {
                        "text": "Best Writing"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "category": {
            "id": "writer",
            "text": "Writer"
          },
        },
        {
          "name": {
            "id": "nm1624755",
            "nameText": {
              "text": "James Reed"
            },
            "awardNominations": {
              "total": 0,
              "edges": []
            }
          },
          "category": {
            "id": "writer",
            "text": "Writer"
          },
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

An example scored award should look like this:

```
{
  "id": "an0975781",
  "isWinner": true,
  "award": { ... },
  "score": 1.5
}
```

Once all the manipulation is done, the data needs to be in exactly the same shape as it was initially and with no null values. So in the case of the last array `awardsNominations.edges` it should be `[]` as it was, and not `{ node: { score: null }}` or anything else.

To achieve this I have created an aggregation pipeline:

```
[
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$principalCredits', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$principalCredits.credits', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$principalCredits.credits.name.awardNominations.edges', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'eventsCollection', 
      'localField': 'principalCredits.credits.name.awardNominations.edges.node.award.event.id', 
      'foreignField': 'id',
      'as': 'matchingEvent'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$matchingEvent', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
    }
  }, {
    '$addFields': {
      'principalCredits.credits.name.awardNominations.edges.node.score': {
        '$multiply': [
          '$matchingEvent.importance', {
            '$cond': {
              'if': '$principalCredits.credits.name.awardNominations.edges.node.isWinner', 
              'then': 1.5, 
              'else': 1.2
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The above pipeline assigns the `score` to each award. However, the null values are still there and I have absolutely no idea how to `group` it back together. I have tried to group with:

```
{
  '$group': {
    '_id': '$id', 
    'titleDoc': {
      '$first': '$$ROOT'
    }, 
    'allPrincipalCredits': {
      '$push': '$principalCredits'
    }
  }
}
```

To keep the root and then somehow sort all the records back into shape but could not get back to the orginal object structure.

Any help in putting it all together will be much appriciated!

I'm fairly good with simple aggregations, but this seems to be too much for me currently and would love to learn how to `$group` things back properly.

I've tried and put together all the knowledge I have so far from different sources and similar answers but can't seem to get it to work.

Lookup collection `eventsCollection` contains objects like this:

```
{  
  "_id": { "$oid": "62c57125d6943d92f83f6fff" },  
  "id": "ev0030197",  
  "text": "#AmLatino Film Festival",  
  "importance": 1
}
```

Comment: So score is importance * either 1.2 or 1.5.    Any cases where importance will not be found in the lookup?    Does that imply importance = 0?

Comment: Ideally, it should assign `1.0` or simply `1` if there is no event found in the lookup, but that will be an extreme situation and most likely won't happen

Comment: How many docs in the `principalCredits` collection, and is the resulting multiplied score updated back into the DB or only emitted?

Comment: Currently `principalCredits` max length is `3` objects, however, it could potentially go up to `10`. I am intending to build a View on top of a collection and it will keep on recalculating the score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the "rule" in restoring to original structure is that for each `$unwind` you did to "deconstruct" the document you now have to do a `$group` to restore it.

As you can imagine in such a pipeline this could be VERY cumbersome. but definitely doable.
However let me propose a different approach that is still very messy but much easier compared to the alternative, additionally it is more efficient from a performance perspective.

(just minor sidenot the reason your score is still `null` is because you have a syntax error in your `$multiply` function)

Anyways, The idea is to first gather all the unique event ids that exist in the in nested documents.
Then execute one lookup to fetch all the relevant events.
And finally adding the `score` field using `$map` and `$mergeDocuments` instead of `$unwind`ing and `$group`ing, like so:

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JYaOyLdCwmz)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      allEvents: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            $map: {
              input: "$principalCredits",
              in: {
                $map: {
                  input: "$$this.credits",
                  as: "credit",
                  in: {
                    $map: {
                      input: "$$credit.name.awardNominations.edges",
                      as: "edge",
                      in: "$$edge.node.award.event.id"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            "$concatArrays": [
              {
                "$reduce": {
                  input: "$$this",
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: {
                    "$concatArrays": [
                      "$$this",
                      "$$value"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "eventsCollection",
      "localField": "allEvents",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "matchingEvents"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      principalCredits: {
        $map: {
          input: "$principalCredits",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                credits: {
                  $map: {
                    input: "$$this.credits",
                    as: "credit",
                    in: {
                      $mergeObjects: [
                        "$$credit",
                        {
                          name: {
                            "$mergeObjects": [
                              "$$credit.name",
                              {
                                "awardNominations": {
                                  "$mergeObjects": [
                                    "$$credit.name.awardNominations",
                                    {
                                      edges: {
                                        $map: {
                                          input: "$$credit.name.awardNominations.edges",
                                          as: "edge",
                                          in: {
                                            node: {
                                              $mergeObjects: [
                                                "$$edge.node",
                                                {
                                                  score: {
                                                    "$multiply": [
                                                      {
                                                        $cond: [
                                                          "$$edge.node.isWinner",
                                                          1.5,
                                                          1.2
                                                        ]
                                                      },
                                                      {
                                                        $first: {
                                                          $map: {
                                                            input: {
                                                              $filter: {
                                                                input: "$matchingEvents",
                                                                as: "matchedEvent",
                                                                cond: {
                                                                  $eq: [
                                                                    "$$matchedEvent.id",
                                                                    "$$edge.node.award.event.id"
                                                                  ]
                                                                }
                                                              }
                                                            },
                                                            as: "matched",
                                                            in: "$$matched.importance"
                                                          }
                                                        }
                                                      }
                                                    ]
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              ]
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "allEvents",
      "matchingEvents"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JYaOyLdCwmz)

I will just mention that you can make this much much much cleaner by involving some code while keeping the same approach suggested. first getting unique `eventid` with `distinct`. then fetching the matching importance for each event. Finally execute a single query using `arrayFilters` you can construct with this information.

- Final side not is that the provided pipeline did not deal with `null` or missing values. So if an array is missing an error will be thrown as `$map` expects input to be a valid array.
  This can easily be solved by just wrapping each of these expressions with `$ifNull`, like so:

```
{
    $map: {
        input: {$ifNull: ["$$this.credits",[]]}
    }
}
```

This will also replace `null` values with an empty `[]`

Comment: Way to go Tom.   The `$map/$filter` is the "lookup" I was looking for; got caught in `$group` death spiral.  :-)

Comment: At least I wasn't alone with the `$group` death spiral Buzz, amazing answer Tom, forever grateful. I guess the question in my head is how can I learn to develop such pipes (fairly quickly) and how advanced is this pipe in your opinion, Tom? Is this an expert level?

Comment: IMHO, yes, this is expert level, both in terms of understanding the functional programming cascade with `map` and the clever use of `map` in concert with `mergeObjects` to preserve each item in the map flow but be able to then step down one more level i.e. `$$this.credits`.  The final `$first/$map/$filter` is only slightly less exotic as a means to extract a single field from an object in an array of objects.

Comment: It was definitely one of the lesser pleasant queries i had the pleasure to write :), I will say that structure manipulation is the concept i see most people struggle with here on stackoverflow. Once you get fluent with the operator set provided it becomes much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The deep buried keys (`...award.event.id`) in arrays confounds an easy approach without  1) messing up the structure as the OP has noted   2) incurring potentially very expensive multiple `$unwind` calls.

Recommendation:  Two pass approach.  Get the necessary `importance` values for the `principalCredits` objects in question, then go back and manually iterate over the collection, diving into the structure and applying the logic `score = importance * isWinner? 1.2 : 1.5`

**PASS 1: Get the ev data**

```js
c=db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project: {
        XX: {$reduce: {
            // Rapidly get to things we need to lookup:                                                
            input: '$principalCredits.credits.name.awardNominations.edges.node.award.event.id',
            // We end up with a mess incl. empty arrays...                                             
            //   [ [[ev1,ev2], [ev3,ev4]], [], [[ev1,...], []  ... ] ]                                 
            // Need to collapse all those arrays of arrays of arrays into                              
            // a single list of ev values, hence a reduce within a reduce:                             
            initialValue: [],
            in: {$concatArrays: [
                '$$value',
                {$reduce: {
                    input: '$$this',
                    initialValue: [],
                        in: {$concatArrays: [ '$$value', '$$this' ] }
                }} ]}
        }}
    }}

    // XX is now [ ev1,ev2,ev3,ev4,ev1 ... ]                                                           
    // The empty arrays are ignored.  Don't worry about dupes.                                         
    ,{$lookup: {
        from: "Xev",
        let: { evids: "$XX" },
        pipeline: [
            {$match: {$expr: {$in: ["$id","$$evids"]} } }
        ],
        as: 'XX' // overwrite XX...                                                                    
    }}
]);

evdict = {}
c.forEach(function(d) {
    d['XX'].forEach(function(ww) {
        evdict[ww['id']] = ww;
    });
});

{
    "ev0003786" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("62cd7f8138d0fbc0eacfb17f"),
        "id" : "ev0003786",
        "text" : "Millennium Docs Against Gravity",
        "importance" : 1
    },
    "ev0000351" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("62cd7f8138d0fbc0eacfb180"),
        "id" : "ev0000351",
        "text" : "International Documentary Association",
        "importance" : 2
    },
    "ev0000571" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("62cd7f8138d0fbc0eacfb181"),
        "id" : "ev0000571",
        "text" : "Royal Television Society, UK",
        "importance" : 3
    }
}
```

**PASS 2: Iterate main collection**
Left as exercise to reader.

Note that if

1. The number of events is small.
2. There is no need or value in performing `$match` on the initial `principalCredits` collection (i.e. before the fancy `$project/$reduce`) to significantly reduce the lookup set into `events`

then this whole thing is unnecessary.   Simply slurp *all* events into `evdict` with a quick `find` and proceed to pass 2.

There is *potentially* a very cool solution that can do this in one pass

**UPDATED**

See Tom's answer below.
Note to MongoDB 5.0 users:  The new `$getField` function allows you to pluck out fields by name instead of having to use the standard trick of using dot notation in the `$in` clause to access the field.  This might be clearer to some:

```js
{$getField: {
    "field": "importance",
    "input": {
      $first: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$matchingEvents",
          as: "matchedEvent",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$matchedEvent.id",
              "$$edge.node.award.event.id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: And I believe I need that "very cool" one pipe solution (even if expensive and not performant for now) as the way the rest is currently set up in our database is that another view (think of it as total aggregation) is doing $lookup to all sorts of calculated views (this will be one of them) and delivers a unique perspective (analytics) for the whole set of data points. Also, I don't really have access to any code space, where I could hold variables (for now), all I have is Mongo Compass & lots of unique views and handful of raw data collections