# MongoDB Inner Array Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following Mongo Document. I need the output for all SID =100 as shown. How can this be achieved. Tried different ways.

As seen, there are multiple array levels. The input has collection of SIDs with all products.

**Input**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123456",
    "Continent": {
      "Country": [
        [
          "US",
          {
            "State": [
              [
                100,
                {
                  "Product": "Corn",
                  "SID": 100
                }
              ],
              [
                200,
                {
                  "Product": "Maze",
                  "SID": 200
                }
              ],
              [
                100,
                {
                  "Product": "Corn-HB",
                  "SID": 100
                }
              ]
            ],
            
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Here the out has only the collection of SID = 100, but it preserves the input format

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "123456",
    "Continent": {
      "Country": [
        [
          "US",
          {
            "State": [
              [
                100,
                {
                  "Product": "Corn",
                  "SID": 100
                }
              ],
              [
                100,
                {
                  "Product": "Corn-HB",
                  "SID": 100
                }
              ]
            ],
            
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Any chance you can redesign the data?  It looks like 'Country' is an array of 2 item "tuples": `[ "statename", { State: [], maybeOther: ... } ]`  and `State` also has tuples instead of named key:value pairs.   Excessive use of lists makes it difficult for the client side application.   You end up with a lot of `doc[n][0][1]` path refs.

Comment: No, this is existing format with huge amounts of data

Comment: Are there any other countries? if so what is the structure for those?. also what Mongo version are you using?\

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple countries. Also currently its MongoDB 4.0, planning to upgrade to 5.0 by year end

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question comments, this data design is a bit odd but a solution can be achieved using the `$function` function (starting in v4.4 Sep 2020) which avoids maps of maps of reduce, etc.:

```js
var keeper_sid = 100;

db.foo.aggregate([
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$function: {
        body: function(obj, keeper) {
            var country_arr = obj['Continent']['Country'];

            for(var n1 = 0; n1 < country_arr.length; n1++) {
                var tuple1 = country_arr[n1];

                var state_arr = tuple1[1]['State'];

                // Walk the State array backwards to ease deletions.               
                for(var n2 = state_arr.length - 1; n2 >= 0; n2--) {
                    var tuple2 = state_arr[n2];
                    if(tuple2[1]['SID'] != keeper) {
                        state_arr.splice(n2,1);
                    }
                }
            }
            return obj;
        },
        args: [ "$$ROOT", keeper_sid ],
        lang: "js"
    }}
  }}
]);
```

This is straightforward but it does make assumptions about the structure e.g. extracting the second (`[1]`) item from the "tuples."   The code can be reduced a bit more but intermediate variables (`tuple1,2`) are shown to make the whole thing a little more clear.

Comment: Could not test this solution since we are still using MongoDB 4.0. Hopefully after upgrade to 5.0. Is there similar solution for 4.0?

Comment: No.  This is Tom level pipelining.    Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72949606 to get a sense of what it takes to walk arrays of arrays whilst preserving format.